# What does mean - in `netstat -tupn` output?

Tags: network-monitoring

Here is the output of `sudo netstat -tupn`

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      5 192.168.1.100:55729     91.190.218.66:443       ESTABLISHED 16422/skype     
tcp        0      1 192.168.1.100:34790     95.26.153.202:61189     LAST_ACK    -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:41233     94.127.69.2:80          ESTABLISHED 21961/firefox   
tcp        1      1 192.168.1.100:38724     195.82.146.121:80       LAST_ACK    -               
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:53279         127.0.0.1:6379          CLOSE_WAIT  7510/ruby       
tcp        0    150 192.168.1.100:60051     95.26.255.169:51413     FIN_WAIT1   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:58343     157.55.56.162:443       ESTABLISHED 16422/skype     
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:59039     64.4.61.73:443          ESTABLISHED 16422/skype     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3493          127.0.0.1:35957         ESTABLISHED 2616/upsd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35957         127.0.0.1:3493          ESTABLISHED 2620/upsmon     
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:47845     74.125.143.16:993       ESTABLISHED 15683/thunderbird
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:53280         127.0.0.1:6379          CLOSE_WAIT  7510/ruby       
tcp        0    196 192.168.1.100:48569     94.100.180.74:995       ESTABLISHED 15683/thunderbird
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:33087     94.25.137.99:443        ESTABLISHED 1020/tmp --disk-cac
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:52397     85.65.133.142:50853     TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:56490     95.26.153.202:61189     TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.100:46865     94.229.242.27:60456     TIME_WAIT   -               
udp6       0      0 ::1:33424               ::1:33424               ESTABLISHED 7430/postgres
```

What does - mean in *PID/Program name* column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means, that it is not connected, so there is no programm running behind the port and this means there is no PID (Process ID) for the programm.

The Port is open but not connected to any software. But a software is listening on the specific port, i.e. Apache2 on port 80 or SSH on port 22.